# Use element to style inside <div>

Tags: html, css

The `emb` is not a class but an element. Can I use this element to style the `div` or, the only way to do it is making `emb` a class such as `.emb`?

```html
<div style=emb>
  Hello
</div>

<style>
  emb {
    font-weight: 500;
    font-style: italic;
    background: transparent;
    font-size: 18px
  }
</style>
```

Comment: define it as class and then styling is more useful. also you can use id to do that. except id name should be used only one time in a single file.

Comment: @SaikatRoyPlease don't advise id for styling purposes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use emb as a class or id for styling your div tag and you can also use a separate css file.

```
<div class="emb"> 
Hello
</div>

<style>

    .emb {
   font-weight: 500;
   font-style: italic;
   background: transparent;
   font-size: 18px
    }

</style>
```

Here you can also use in-line css also.

```
<div style="font-weight: 500;
       font-style: italic;
       background: transparent;
       font-size: 18px;"> 
Hello
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not how it works. You need to do e.g.:

```html
<div class="emb">
  Hello
</div>

<style>
  .emb {
    font-weight: 500;
    font-style: italic;
    background: transparent;
    font-size: 18px
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you cant use things like that to style element.
Here, style is a attribute to div tag. You can use it directly to style your div.

```
<div style="font-weight: 500;
       font-style: italic;
       background: transparent;
       font-size: 18px;"> 
Hello
</div>
```

But inorder to define class or id, you need to use class or id attribute. Or you can use tagname to style.

```
<div class='emb'> 
Hello
</div>

<style>

   .emb {
       font-weight: 500;
       font-style: italic;
       background: transparent;
       font-size: 18px
    }
    
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Mistake in OP's code

`style=emb` is not a correct way to assign the class to an element.

#### Correction

To use an element to style inside div, you have to give it a `class` or `id` that maps the element to the `style.css` where you define the styles. Also ,replace `emb` with `.emb`, you have to add `.` decorator while using `class`

#### Some info

We have mainly 3 types of CSS decorators which we use to associate the HTML component with CSS component.

- Simple tag like

```
<div > 
        Hello
</div>

<style>
   div {
   font-weight: 500;
    }
</style>
```

- Use `class` decorator with `.`

```
<div class="emb"> 
        Hello
</div>

<style>
   .emb {
   font-weight: 500;
    }
</style>
```

- Use `class` decorator with `.`

```
<div id="emb"> 
        Hello
</div>

<style>
   #emb {
   font-weight: 500;
    }
</style>
```

#### Working code

```html
<div class="emb">
  Hello
</div>

<style>
  .emb {
    font-weight: 500;
    font-style: italic;
    background: transparent;
    font-size: 18px
  }
</style>
```

#### Alternate method with code

```html
<div id="emb">
  Hello
</div>

<style>
  #emb {
    font-weight: 500;
    font-style: italic;
    background: transparent;
    font-size: 18px
  }
</style>
```